# Retrieve COSMOS Connection String or Primary Key in javascript running in azure pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-pipelines

I have created azure pipeline using classic editor and executes test.js file using pipeline. I need to retrieve azure COSMOS key which could be used in the js file.

Tried by installing [Cosmos DB Key Retriever extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RasmusWatjen.CosmosKeyRetrieverExtension#:~:text=Retrieve%20Cosmos%20DB%20keys&text=You%20must%20pass%20in%20an,with%20a%20name%20you%20define.) but it doesnt show ADD option in the pipeline.

How can this be resolved? How cosmos key be fetched within js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can this be resolved? How cosmos key be fetched within js file?

We strongly suggest using a `config.js` file to set your app's configurations, including the PRIMARY KEY of Azure Cosmos DB. Check related official documents here: [#1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-nodejs), [#2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-get-started#Config), [#3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application).

It seems that you want to avoid writing the key directly in code, then you can consider:

1.Copy the primary key from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-nodejs#update-your-connection-string) in Azure Web portal, and then [create a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group) in Azure Devops pipelines to store that value. (Change variable type to secret !)

Also you can choose to host that value [using Azure key valut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/access-secrets-from-keyvault) and then [link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault) in current variable group. (If you don't want to host the value in Varibale group directly.)

2.[Link the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-variable-group) to your current classic pipeline.

3.Then you can use [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to insert the value of your Primary key into the `config.js` or `xx.js` file. You should run your other tasks after this task so that you can use the key in your js file.

Assuming I have the variable `TheKeyIfCosmos` to store the primary key.

[image]

Then specifying this format in config.js file:

```
key: "#{TheKeyOfCosmos}#",
```

[image]

After running that task, the content in config.js would be real `key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",`.

After above steps you can test/run your app with primary key.

Comment: Thank you... It was really helpful :). But is there a way by which we can avoid manually copying the PRIMARY KEY to pipeline.Can the key could be retrieved from azure itself. Because if key gets expired or changed, we need to update the config file.

Comment: @am831 Have you tried the third-party extension [Cosmos DB Key Retriever extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RasmusWatjen.CosmosKeyRetrieverExtension#:~:text=Retrieve%20Cosmos%20DB%20keys&text=You%20must%20pass%20in%20an,with%20a%20name%20you%20define.) really? The extension could save the key to one output variable automatically, which simplify the step1 and step2 above. What's the result if you run this order:  Cosmos DB account retriever task=>Replace token task=>Then your other tasks? Let me know if it helps~

Comment: @am831 Also for `Because if key gets expired or changed, we need to update the config file.` Personal idea, if you have specific reason to change the key for security. If would be better if the pipeline will fail unless you update the config file, an extra security to avoid someone can access your key via the pipeline,